# translate javascript code to mode readable code with if and else

Tags: javascript, reverse-engineering, if-statement, logical-operators

What that means?

```
e[i] == "-" && (s > 1 || d === null) && ++s, !s && d !== null && (p.push(e[i]), s = 2), "+-".indexOf(e[i]) < (d = null) && (c = 1);
```

can not read so many sumbols without any logic

Comment: Are you trying to reverse-engineer minified code? What is the point of this?

Comment: its a part of free code of mathparser and i have a problem in that string, but i can't fix it because i do not understand such a syntax. Any help would be welcome!

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/ is a good place to make code more readable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (e[i] == "-" && (s > 1 || d === null))
    ++s;

if (!s && d !== null) {
    p.push(e[i]);
    s = 2;
}

if ("+-".indexOf(e[i]) < (d = null))
    c = 1;
```

If you don't come with a C background, the assignment in the last `if` may not appeal to you; in that case:

```
d = null;
if ("+-".indexOf(e[i]) < null)
    c = 1;
```

Comment: THANK YOU! :) indexOf() gives int which is senseless to compare with null. Can be null substituted by something else in this case?

Comment: you could change it to `"+-".indexOf('+') < 0` which is less characters and easier to understand.

Comment: Eric's comment most probably represents the intent of the code. "If `e[i]` is neither `'+'` nor `'-'`, then `c = 1`." How `d = null` fits in, I cannot say. So yes, try to use the second form of the if statement and replace the `< null` with `< 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding some spaces and newlines:

```
e[i] == "-" && (s > 1 || d === null) && ++s,
    !s && d !== null && (p.push(e[i]), s = 2),
    "+-".indexOf(e[i]) < (d = null) && (c = 1);
```

Note, this is a comma expression - it's 3 expressions separated by commas.  Each expression is actually a statement that goes

```
condition && action;
```

You can get away with this in C because of the way `&&` works. for the expression `A && B`, first A is executed, and *only if the result of A is true* is B then executed.  So on its own `A && B;` can be translated to `if(A) B;`.  Of course this only works if the result of the entire expression `A && B` isn't used.

Comment: thx! sorry for stupid question, but can it be written with if and else keywords?

Comment: Thank you! im closer and closer to understanding :) Actually the problem i have here is 3rd expression: comparison indexOf() that null. AS3 makes warning at with point because of comparison type int with null. Can be 3rd expression rewritten to avoid the warning message?